# json listview delete not working android studio

Tags: android, json, listview

I am loading some json into a list view and want to delete items from the list on click and for the item to be deleted from the json. The delete functionality seems to be working. The method delete is called, the items are removed on click and debugging shows the item being removed. However after going to another activity and viewing the list again, the deleted items come back. what am i doing wrong? This is my class:

```
public class edit extends AppCompatActivity 
{

    public ListView pizzaList;
    ListView addicList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    String appreciations;
    String currentPizza;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_activity);
        pizzaList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pizzas);
        registerForContextMenu(pizzaList);

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        pizzaList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        pizzaList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                delete(view,position);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        try {
            FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();

            String str = fileManager.ReadFile(this);

            if (str != null) {
                JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(str);

                String outputText = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String pizzaName = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    int price = jsonObject.getInt("price");

                    outputText = outputText + " " + pizzaName + "  " + " $" + price + "\n";

                    appreciations = outputText;
                    list.add(appreciations);

                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    outputText = "";
                }
            } else {
                Toast to = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No saved Pizzas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                to.show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void delete(View view, int pos)
    {
        try {
            FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();

            String str = fileManager.ReadFile(this);

            if (str != null) 
            {
                JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(str);

                JSONObject jsonObject = jarray.getJSONObject(pos);

                jarray.remove(pos);
                list.remove(pos);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(jarray);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                Toast to = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No saved Pizzas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                to.show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are just removing from Json value which you are storing locally and in adapter you didnt remove from FileManager, you can add you FileManager in question

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove the item from the database, use asynchronous request such as volley or robospice for it.  Then instead of making the request when coming back you would use the data stored on the cache the second time and only make the request again when data has been changed.  You can create your cache logic in your application class to make it visible throughout your app.